# Synchronizing data between server and client

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, client-server

When it comes to mobile applications a lot of the time the client is going to be offline.

Right now when the user submits data on the client it is saved locally and then when they press the sync button everything is pushed and pulled between the client and the server.

What would be the best practices when it comes to synchronization of data?

Server side I have a very large MS SQL Server and client side I have sqlite at my hands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find [this (This is Microsoft Application Architecture Guide v2.0, Oct 2009)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658108.aspx#Synchronization)  useful. I am facing the same problem here at work, and *I* did find these guidelines useful early in the process of thinking.

To share my experience, I think the major decision comes from the problem you are trying to solve. If You're facing a single, fixed, mature business domain (i.e, rarely changing your db schema and you face just one or two clients) you can build your own data synchronization framework. This is far better than using commercial or non-commercial frameworks in terms of ease-of-use and adjustment + performance. + Store-and-forward is a very good feature that can overcome your connectivity issues.

However, If you are facing a changing (not necessarily expanding) business domain, or maybe different clients with different requirements you might want to use a mature framework (like Microsoft Synch Framework) to do some parts of the work for you and you can focus on the adjustments needed to your requirements.

I hope this isn't too general.

Comment: That MS link is gone. It opens some mobile app guidelines instead.